# AngularJS: ngResource 500 internal server error

Tags: angularjs, ngresource, angularjs-ng-resource

I have a problem in getting list of users using `$resource`.

I am making a webservice call using `$resource` to get list of users. It works most of the time, but when ever the response takes some time I am getting *500 internal server error*.

The code I am using to call the webservice:

```
$resource("user/referral/getUserList", {}, {
            query: {
                method: 'GET'
            }
        })
```

I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: What is the exact error your are receiving, what's the full error response?

Comment: It's a problem on your server. We can't help you unless you find out what the error is, it is not related to the code above.

Comment: It looks like the request is timed out before the response from the server. Do i need to set any request time like that?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are  missing a "/" at the left.

```
user/referral/getUserList
```

Please keep this as well if you want to have the result as an array.

```
'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Glassfish.
It's a bug in Glassfish 4.1.1 https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2888

I was able to fix it in this way:

In glassfish/modules/org.eclipse.persistence.moxy.jar fix META-INF/MANIFEST.MF Just append the following to Import-Package:

,org.xml.sax.helpers,javax.xml.parsers;resolution:=optional,javax.naming;resolution:=optional

in 72 line and restart GF